# How to compile a simple program with OpenSSL?

Tags: c++, gcc, openssl, compilation, ld

I am trying to compile a simple ssl program (it was taken from the openssl book source code).
The program has the following files: common.h common.c client.c server.c

I have installed openssl 0.9.7 so I have the same version with the book.
I have downloaded the source and ./Configure, make, make test, make install in the home directory.

In the common.h there are the following includes:

```
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/x509v3.h>
```

I run **gcc -Wall common.c client.c -o client** but I get the following errors:

```
common.c: In function ‘init_OpenSSL’:
common.c:12:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘THREAD_setup’
/tmp/ccvI3HX4.o: In function `handle_error':
common.c:(.text+0x3a): undefined reference to `ERR_print_errors_fp'
/tmp/ccvI3HX4.o: In function `init_OpenSSL':
common.c:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `THREAD_setup'
common.c:(.text+0x5a): undefined reference to `SSL_library_init'
common.c:(.text+0x97): undefined reference to `SSL_load_error_strings'
/tmp/ccRA0Co9.o: In function `do_client_loop':
client.c:(.text+0x71): undefined reference to `BIO_write'
/tmp/ccRA0Co9.o: In function `main':
client.c:(.text+0xbb): undefined reference to `BIO_new_connect'
client.c:(.text+0x106): undefined reference to `BIO_ctrl'
client.c:(.text+0x18e): undefined reference to `BIO_free'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Obviously it cannot link to the header files...
When I run as suggested in one forum **gcc -Wall common.c client.c -o client -lcrypto -lssl** I get

```
common.c: In function ‘init_OpenSSL’:
common.c:12:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘THREAD_setup’
/tmp/cc2gjx8W.o: In function `init_OpenSSL':
common.c:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `THREAD_setup'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But adding -lpthread won't help resolve the problem...

Any idea why this happens and how to solve it?

My guess is that lcrypto and lssl are installed by default in ubuntu and by doing -lcypto is telling the linker to look at the systems headers and not the openssl installation ones...

Any help or pointers is appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean `libraries` when you are saying `headers`?

Comment: If you're worried about which library is being linked to, specify explicit paths using the -L option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In some code versions of openssl book, the thread related functions are stored in reentrant.c, (in fact the declaration of TRHEAD_setup, in the version i've seen is there), so try with:

```
gcc -Wall common.c client.c reentrant.c -o client -lcrypto -lssl
```

Comment: Yes, you were right! this fixed the problem for me although in my version reentrant.c was not even mentioned

Comment: Where do I get the file reentrant.c ?

Comment: The source code is at https://resources.oreilly.com/examples/9780596002701/