# How to use OpenSSL on Windows? Compile error

Tags: windows, dll, linker, openssl

I have a problem similar to [Openssl how to compile a simple program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304086/openssl-how-to-compile-a-simple-program) but I'm using Windows 7 (so advice to compile `reentrant.c` doesn't work). I have a Windows port of OpenSSL from GnuWin32 and in Qt Creator I try to build project. In my .pro file I put the following lines:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\gnuwin32\include
LIBS += -LC:\gnuwin32\bin -lssl32
```

But compiler still writes:

```
undefined reference to `BIO_s_file'
undefined reference to `BIO_new'
undefined reference to `BIO_ctrl'
undefined reference to `PEM_read_bio_X509'
(...)
undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_free'
collect2.exe:-1: błąd: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
Does anyone have any idea what's wrong with the linker? Headers are included, `LIBS += -L C:\gnuwin32\bin -lssl32` is in .pro file...

Comment: Link with  -lssl and -lcrypto and -lws2_32 and -lgdi32 in that order with those exact names. Now sure why you have a -lssl32. There is no 32 at the end of it afaik.. unless you renamed it.

Comment: `-lssl32` may not be correct. On Windows, the library is named `libeay32.dll`; it is not named `libssl32.dll`.

Comment: Thanks! I used `-leay32` and it works. But I have also `libssl32.dll` in `gnuwin32/bin` directory, I didn't rename nothing so what is it?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need the path to where libssl32 exists after another -L argument.  Also I think that you might need a space after that -L (I am not 100% sure but I know a space will work).

Comment: I tried to write library path with space, without space, with quotes, without quotes - still the same error. But I didn't think about double "L" (Is this what you meant, right?). So when in .pro file is:
    LIBS += -LL C:\gnuwin32\bin -lssl32
I see error: 
    cannot find C:\gnuwin32\bin: Permission denied
    ld returned 1 exit status
It's the same problem as descibed here - http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/40567 but it remains without any answer.

Comment: The -L entries are singluar and addative for example gcc -L C:\windows\blah -L C:\path\to\openssl32 -lssl32 -lotherlib can you post more of the error so I can get a better look?

Comment: It was the full error, I ommited only a few analogous `undefined reference` to OpenSSL's functions.