# How to fix: fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: No such file or directory in RedHat 7

Tags: module, linux-kernel, openssl, redhat

I have RedHat Enterprise Linux Server 7, and I downloaded the linux kernel version 4.12.10 which I am trying to compile but when I execute the following command:

```
make modules
```

I get the following error:

```
scripts/sign-file.c:25:30: fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone have an idea to fix this please ?

Comment: OpenSSL is not used in kernel modules that I am aware. The kernel provides its own crypto, and some of the OpenSSL team contributes to it like Andy Polyakov. Its odd to see OpenSSL in the message above. I guess its some helper program or something to bootstrap things. Its definitely not the kernel proper.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compile .c file with OpenSSL includes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368683/how-to-compile-c-file-with-openssl-includes), [Openssl how to compile a simple program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6304086/608639), [Compiling C program with OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43644785/608639), etc.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

To fix this problem, you have to install OpenSSL development package, which is available in standard repositories of all modern Linux distributions.

To install OpenSSL development package on Debian, Ubuntu or their derivatives:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

To install OpenSSL development package on Fedora, CentOS or RHEL:

```
$ sudo yum install openssl-devel
```

**Edit :**
As @isapir has pointed out, for Fedora version>=22 use the DNF package manager :

```
dnf install openssl-devel
```

Comment: In modern Fedora: `dnf install -y openssl-devel`

Comment: On Ubuntu, `libssl-dev` gave me what I needed (while `openssl-dev` did not).

Comment: I have install libssl-dev in ubuntu 22.04, but this error persist, is possible that openssl v3.0.2 dont include this header?

Answer (score 35):

For [Alpine Linux](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86_64/openssl-dev):

```
apk add openssl-dev
```

Answer (score 4):

On CYGwin, you can install this as a typical package in the first screen. Look for

`libssl-devel`

Comment: After facing up a lot of make errors from the official depository, it seems that cygwin packages works well with cygwin compilers ^^

Answer (score 1):

for resolving this issue install:

```
# yum install openssl openssl-devel
```

and then try again to do `make bzImage`.